# Is there a way to change OS X (Mavericks) Reminders default alert time?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, reminder

I am using extensively Reminders to organize myself. I like using the alert to remind me of stuff I have to do. My problem is that the default time is 9am which doesn't suit me. Is there any way to change this?

To duplicate this behavior I drag a reminder to a date in the small calendar on the bottom.